# FO:XSL apex number superscript for letter

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Currently i'm trying to put a superscript number over a letter in xslt, but i've no found nothing for to do that on internet, it must be like  km², thank you for interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the attribute `vertical-align="super"` of `fo:inline` element.

```
<fo:block>km<fo:inline vertical-align="super">2</fo:inline></fo:block>
```

But it may depend on the `font` type.